# On $\ell_1$ to $\ell_1$ operator norm of matrix with inverse Wishart distribution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, st.statistics, random-matrices

Consider a random $n\times p$ matrix $X$ with $n\ll p$ and all entries of $X$ i.i.d. standard normal. For this $X$, the system of linear equations $y=Xw$ has infinitely many solutions, and the one with smallest $\ell^2$ norm is $\hat{w}=X^T(XX^T)^{-1}y.$ Based on this, I am interested in understanding $$\|X^T(XX^T)^{-1}\|_{\ell_1^n\to \ell_1^p}\leq \|X^T\|_{\ell_1^p\to \ell_1^n}\cdot \|(XX^T)^{-1}\|_{\ell_1^n\to \ell_1^n}.$$

The first term can be bounded using Chevet's inequality, but the closest thing I can find for the second term is [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86356/expected-operator-norm-of-inverse-wishart-matrix) question, which deals with $\|\cdot \|_{\ell_2^n\to \ell_2^n}$.

So is anything known about arbitrary operator norms of the inverse Wishart distribution? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about the particular question you ask, but my instinct is that the factorization you choose to get the inequality you state may not be such a good idea. The reason is that in the expression $X^\top (XX^\top)^{-1}$, eigenvectors of $XX^\top$ that have small eigenvalue get "blown up" by $(XX^\top)^{-1}$ and then "shrunk back down" by applying $X^\top$ again. When you split the product up and take norms of each component, you're not seeing this cancellation, so you could end up with an upper bound that is very bad

Comment: Does this kind of argument apply even though the relevant quantities are not the eigenvalues/vectors?

Comment: Well, roughly speaking, any reasonable norm on square matrices is going to be big when there are some large singular values (= eigenvalues for matrices of the form $XX^\top$). But I agree that what I outlined above is only a note of caution, not definite evidence that you will get a bad upper bound